# An easy way to compute $\sum a_k^{a-a_k}\bmod K$, where $a=\sum a_k$

Tags: summation, exponentiation

I am given programming assignment, and I am asked to fit into time limit of test cases.

But because of this exponentiation, I don't see how.

Since exponentiation is an expensive operation, I want to do it less number of time.

Is there any simplification of this, so that I can do the same operation in less time?

$$\left(a_1^{a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5+\cdots+a_n}+ a_2^{a_1+a_3+a_4+\cdots+a_n)} +\cdots + a_n^{a_1+a_2+a_3+ \cdots +a_n-1} \right) \bmod K = \text{?}$$
 $ 1\le a_i \le 4600,  1\le K \le 1200000, 100 \le n \le 3000$

Comment: How large are the values $a_i, n, K$?

Comment: @qwr added to the answer

Comment: The value of $n$ matters as well.

Comment: @qwr n is between 100 and 3000

Comment: Is this question from an ongoing contest?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche No, I was trying to write code which passes test cases. Not an ongoing contest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about evading exponentiation by taking log then it becomes the sum of the powers into the log and then you must antilog and add.

So each term will be the anti log of 
$  log((a1)^(a2 + ... +an)) = (a2+a3+...+) log(a1)$

Comment: I think taking antilog will cost same amount of time, isn't it ?

Comment: Perphaps but worth a try

Comment: It gives floating number, which should be rounded up or down, and thus not precise. But it was a good try ! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let $s = a_1 + \dots + a_n$.

The sum is $a_1^{s-a_1} + a_2^{s-a_2} + \dots + a_n^{s-a_n} \mod K$

Depending on what values $a_i$ and $K$ take, this may be fast enough to compute with modular exponentiation.

Answer (score 0):

If we call $a_1+a_2+...+_n=a$,

We can rewrite:

$$\displaystyle a_1^ {(a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5+..+a_n)}+ a_2^{(a_1+a_3+a_4+...+a_n)} +...+a_n^{(a_1+a_2+a_3...+a_{n-1})} $$

Like this:

$$\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i^ {a-a_i} $$

Hence:

$$\displaystyle (\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i^ {a-a_i}) \mod K \\= \sum_{i=1}^{n} (a_i^ {a-a_i}\mod K)\\= \sum_{i=1}^{n} (a_i \mod K)^ {a-a_i} \mod K$$

In the last expression, you first take $\mod K$ operator and thus the base will be decreased in order to increase calculation speed.